# Conditional formatting for partial duplicates in Pandas and Excel

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas

I have the following csv data named `reviews.csv`:

```
Movie,Reviewer,Sentence,Tag,Sentiment,Text,
Jaws,John,s1,Plot,Positive,The plot was great,
Jaws,Mary,s1,Plot,Positive,The plot was great,
Jaws,John,s2,Acting,Positive,The acting was OK,
Jaws,Mary,s2,Acting,Neutral,The acting was OK,
Jaws,John,s3,Scene,Positive,The visuals blew me away,
Jaws,Mary,s3,Effects,Positive,The visuals blew me away,
Vertigo,John,s1,Scene,Negative,The scenes were terrible,
Vertigo,Mary,s1,Acting,Negative,The scenes were terrible,
Vertigo,John,s2,Plot,Negative,The actors couldn’t make the story believable,
Vertigo,Mary,s2,Acting,Positive,The actors couldn’t make the story believable,
Vertigo,John,s3,Effects,Negative,The effects were awful,
Vertigo,Mary,s3,Effects,Negative,The effects were awful,
```

My goal is to turn this csv file into an Excel spreadsheet with conditional formatting. Specifically, I’d like to apply the following rules:

1. If the ‘Movie’, ‘Sentence’, ‘Tag’, and ‘Sentiment’ values are the same, the whole row should be green.
2. If the ‘Movie’, ‘Sentence’, and ‘Tag’ values are the same, but the ‘Sentiment’ value is different, the row should be blue.
3. If the ‘Movie’ and ‘Sentence’ values are the same, but the ‘Tag’ values are different, the row should be red.

So I'd like to create an Excel spreadsheet (.xlsx) that looks like the following:

[image: Spreadsheet with color-coded partial duplicates]

I've been looking at the Styles documentation for Pandas, as well as the conditional formatting tutorials on XlsxWriter, but I just can't seem to put it all together. Here's what I have so far. I can read the csv into a Pandas dataframe, sort it (although I'm not sure that's necessary), and write it back out to an Excel Spreadsheet. How do I do the conditional formatting, and where in the code does that go?

```
def csv_to_xls(source_path, dest_path):
    """
    Convert a csv file to a formatted xlsx spreadsheet
    Input: path to hospital review csv file
    Output: formatted xlsx spreadsheet
    """
    #Read the source file and convert to Pandas dataframe
    df = pd.read_csv(source_path)

    #Sort by Filename, then by sentence number
    df.sort_values(['File', 'Sent'], ascending=[True, True], inplace = True)

    #Create the xlsx file that we'll be writing to
    orig = pd.ExcelWriter(dest_path, engine='xlsxwriter')

    #Convert the dataframe to Excel, create the sheet
    df.to_excel(orig, index=False, sheet_name='report')

    #Variables for the workbook and worksheet
    workbook = orig.book
    worksheet = orig.sheets['report']

    #Formatting for exact, partial, mismatch, gold
    exact = workbook.add_format({'bg_color':'#B7F985'}) #green
    partial = workbook.add_format({'bg_color':'#D3F6F4'}) #blue
    mismatch = workbook.add_format({'bg_color':'#F6D9D3'}) #red

    #Do the conditional formatting somehow

    orig.save()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors of the library I'm going to suggest**

This can be achieved pretty easily with [StyleFrame](https://github.com/DeepSpace2/StyleFrame) and [`DataFrame.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
from styleframe import StyleFrame, Styler

sf = StyleFrame(df)

green = Styler(bg_color='#B7F985')
blue = Styler(bg_color='#D3F6F4')
red = Styler(bg_color='#F6D9D3')

sf.apply_style_by_indexes(sf[df.duplicated(subset=['Movie', 'Sentence'], keep=False)],
                          styler_obj=red)
sf.apply_style_by_indexes(sf[df.duplicated(subset=['Movie', 'Sentence', 'Tag'], keep=False)],
                          styler_obj=blue)
sf.apply_style_by_indexes(sf[df.duplicated(subset=['Movie', 'Sentence', 'Tag', 'Sentiment'],
                                           keep=False)],
                          styler_obj=green)

sf.to_excel('test.xlsx').save()
```

This outputs the following:

[image]

Comment: Just came across this while googling for colour cells in pandas etc. Very cool package.  It's taking quite a while for a dataframe of about 100k rows. Is this normal? Any way to speed it up?

Comment: @SCool Unfortunately speed is an issue with larger dataframes as you found out since StyleFrame has to iterate every single cell in order to apply the style. I'm yet to find a faster approach. Having said that, I'm able to generate a file with 100k rows and 2 columns in a few seconds.

Comment: Ok, I have 60 columns. Takes a few minutes. Anyway, useful package. :)